# How to draw a line using X, Y, Z coordinates from a csv or txt file?

Tags: csv, unity-game-engine, drawing, data-visualization

and I'm having difficulty to drawing a line on the screen using the X, Y, Z coordinates of a CSV or TXT file. I tried with the line render and also with swipe trail, but I could not. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be better if you could provide more information on what you have tried so far. Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

1. Read a file e.g using [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend)

   ```c#
   var fileContent = "";
   (using var reader = new StreamReader(path))
   {
       fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   ```
2. Assuming a CSV/txt content like

   ```c#
   23.46, 1.0, 2.4
   0.003, 7.038, 3

   ...
   ```

   Parse the content e.g. using `SplitCSVLine` from [CSVReader](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSVReader)

   ```c#
   private static string[] SplitCsvLine(string line)
   {
       return (from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(line,
           @"(((?<x>(?=[,\r\n]+))|""(?<x>([^""]|"""")+)""|(?<x>[^,\r\n]+)),?)",     
           System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
           select m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
   }
   ```

   use it together with [float.TryParse(string, out float)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse) like

   ```c#
   var lines = fileContent.Split('/n');
   var points = new List<Vector3>();
   foreach(var line in lines)
   {
       var parts = SplitCsvLine(line);

       float x = float.TryParse(parts[0], out x) ? x : 0;
       float y = float.TryParse(parts[1], out y) ? y : 0;
       float z = float.TryParse(parts[2], out z) ? z : 0;

       points.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
   }
   ```

   where

   ```c#
   float x = float.TryParse(parts[0], out x) ? x : 0;
   ```

   is a short form of writing

   ```c#
   float x;
   if(!float.TryParse(parts[0], out x))
   {
       x = 0;

       // Alternatively you could also declare this point as invalid
       // and not add this point at all
       continue;
   }
   ```

   or, if you know the content will only exactly contain those numeric symbols and commas, no special characters, you could also simply use

   ```c#
   var parts = line.Split(',');
   ```
3. And finally apply those points e.g. to a `LineRenderer` using [SetPositions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html)

   ```c#
   GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPositions(points);
   ```

---

There might be more efficient options though.

Comment: Written on my smartphone so please don't nail me on typos etc ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Unity and I'm still learning C #. I could not understand it well and implement, but I will keep trying

Comment: I was trying to use and modify this example that moves a cube with a coordinate of a CSV file, but applying it to a line render

Comment: `public class CSVFIleReader : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public GameObject cubeTest;
        public TextAsset csvFile;


    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () 


        {
            readCSV();
        }

        void readCSV()
        {
            string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
            for(int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fields = records[i].Split(',');
            cubeTest.transform.Rotate (float.Parse(fields[1]), float.Parse(fields[2]), float.Parse(fields[3]));
        }
    }
}`

Comment: (https://aarlangdi.blogspot.com/2016/07/animating-object-with-csv-txt-file-in.html)